# SIGNAL emit works only in one function, but not in others?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, signals-slots

I have a somewhat strange problem. I'm coding a multithreaded app and am using SIGNALS to communicate the QThread's data to the GUI class data. Without further ado, here is a simplified code.

```
class GUI(uiMainWindow.MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super etc
        self.thread = Thread()
        self.connect(self.thread, SIGNAL("changeStatus(QString)"), self.setStatus, Qt.QueuedConnection)

    def setStatus(self, status):
        self.statusBar.setText(status)


class Thread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, create=True):
        super etc
        self.create = create

    def run(self):
        if self.create:
            create_data()
        if not self.create:
            upload_data()

    def create_data(self):
        self.emit(SIGNAL("changeStatus(QString)"), "Changing the statusbar text")
        #rest of the code

    def upload_data(self):
        self.emit(SIGNAL("changeStatus(QString)"), "Changing the statusbar text")
```

Pretty basic, right? However, here's the problem: the self.emit works only in create_data function, but not in upload_data (or for that matter, in any other function; I tried putting it in `__init__` as well). I tried putting `print "I got the status" + status` in the setStatus function. Again, it works in the create_data() function, but not in the upload_data() function.

The differences between the two functions are relatively minor, and as far as I can tell, nothing is interfering with the self.emit function - in fact, in both cases, self.emit is only 4-5 lines "away" from the function definition.

This is really puzzling to me. Any help? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: again, as far as I can tell, the only difference between the two functions is in the run() - the first one is called if create parameter is True, and the second one if it is False.

Comment: Other than the superfluous `(QString)` in the signal signature, there is nothing wrong with the example code you posted. Please post a complete, runnable example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @ekhumoro: I wish I could do that, but the program is close-source :( So are you saying that QString is completely unnecessary? Should I just leave it blank (i.e. `changeStatus()`)?

Comment: If you're using the old-style syntax, and connecting a python signal to a python callable, then only the name (e.g. `changeState`) is required. See [here](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/old_style_signals_slots.html#connecting-signals-and-slots) for the various possiblilities. Of course, for new projects, it's much better to use the [new-style syntax](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/new_style_signals_slots.html).

Comment: I've been meaning to switch to the new-style signals, but I'm running on a deadline. Perhaps in v2 of the application. Thanks for the tip though, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was right in my post. The difference between Thread() and Thread(create=False) was crucial. I had to define a new method (one was `self.thread = Thread()` and the other `self.diff_thread = Thread(create=False)`) and connect to different slots to make it work.